# Printing the line after or before a regular expression match in Bash

Tags: bash, text-processing

Given a string like the following:

```
BASH - Mplayer Playlist Shuffle
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IB7SCPtbJM8
metalx1000
BASH - Playing Music
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S_-EGoLYCXY
metalx1000
BASH - Burn ISO images with cdrecord in Linux
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BxAEGa9NKs8
metalx1000
BASH - replace space in file names
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MRlUPV1221Y
metalx1000
```

What would be the best way to get the titles, the URLs, and the uploaders into separate variables?

My thought was to find a way to `grep`, `sed`, or `awk` www.youtube.com, and then print the line above it or below it. Then save it into a variable. I haven't had any luck finding a solution that works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this:

```
$ while read -r title
> do
>  read -r url
>  read -r uploader
>  echo "Title is $title "
>  echo "Url is $url "
>  echo "Uploader is $uploader"
> done < file
```

Comment: What is the best way to accomplish the same thing, but using a variable instead of a file? Thanks for your response.

Comment: Just kidding, I believe <<< does the trick. Thanks again.